# Como recorrer un array dentro de otro array indexado

Tags: php, laravel, array

trato de guardar en mi array registros de edificios indexados ya que puedo registrar 1 o mas edificios en un solo formulario, por cada edificio quiero guardar nombre_edificio, numero_aulas, y prefijo_aulas.  Mi codigo es el siguiente

```
 $edificios = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->nombreedificio) ; $i++) {
    $edificio = array();
    $edificio["nombre_edificio"] = $request->nombreedificio[$i];
    $edificio["numero_aulas"] = $request->numeroaulas[$i];
    $edificio["prefijo_aulas"] = $request->prefijoaulas[$i];
    $edificios[$i] = $edificio;
    }
    dd($edificios);
```

Al ejecutar un  dd($edificios); Puedo observar lo siguiente al enviar datos de dos edificios

```
  array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "nombre_edificio" => "edificio1"
    "numero_aulas" => "10"
    "prefijo_aulas" => "a"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "nombre_edificio" => "edificio2"
    "numero_aulas" => "20"
    "prefijo_aulas" => "b"
  ]
]
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo recorrer este array, ya sea con un for o un foreach, de modo que pueda iterar los datos de cada edificio de esta manera y guardarlos (ALGO A SI)

```
for ($c = 0; $c < count($edificios) ; $i++)   {

edificio->nombre_edificio[c]

edificio->numero_aulas[c]

edificio->prefijo_aulas[c]
}
```

Comment: En tu comentario (ALGO ASI), utilizas código para acceder a objetos, para acceder al arreglo debes usar `edificio[$c]['nombre_edificio']`

Comment: Medio este error al tratar de iterar de esa forma   "Undefined offset: 0" <codigo>                             for ($c = 0; $c < count($edificios) ; $i++)   {
$edificio[$c]['nombre_edificio'];
$edificio[$c]['numero_aulas'];
$edificio[$c]['prefijo_aulas'];

}         </codigo>

Comment: la variable a utilizar dentro del for es `$edificios` entonces sería así `edificios[$c]['nombre_edificio']`

Comment: Imagino que el voto negativo es porque pareciera una pregunta duplicada pero busqué en el sitio y no encontré alguna pregunta parecida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorrer con un `for`:

```
for ($c = 0; $c < count($edificios) ; $i++)   {

   edificios[$c]['nombre_edificio'];

   edificios[$c]['numero_aulas'];

   edificios[$c]['prefijo_aulas'];
}
```

Recorrer con un [foreach](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($edificios as $edificio) {

   edificio['nombre_edificio'];

   edificio['numero_aulas'];

   edificio['prefijo_aulas'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### 1. El array

He tratado de reconstruir tu array de edificios.

Si el array es así:

```
$arrEdificios= array(
    array( 
            "nombre_edificio" => "edificio1",
            "numero_aulas" => "10",
            "prefijo_aulas" => "a"
          ),

     array (
             "nombre_edificio" => "edificio2",
             "numero_aulas" => "20",
             "prefijo_aulas" => "b"
            )
) ;

print_r($arrEdificios);
```

Veamos la salida del print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nombre_edificio] => edificio1
            [numero_aulas] => 10
            [prefijo_aulas] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre_edificio] => edificio2
            [numero_aulas] => 20
            [prefijo_aulas] => b
        )

)
```

---

### 2. Lectura del Array

Varias formas de lectura son posibles.

#### A. Almacenando en variables

```
foreach ($arrEdificios as $k=>$v)
{

    $strEdificio=$v["nombre_edificio"];
    $intNumAulas=$v["numero_aulas"];
    $strPrefijoAulas=$v["prefijo_aulas"];

    echo "Edificio: ".$strEdificio."\n";
    echo "num aulas: ".$intNumAulas."\n";
    echo "prefijo: ".$strPrefijoAulas."\n\n";

}
```

#### Salida:

```
Edificio: edificio1
num aulas: 10
prefijo: a

Edificio: edificio2
num aulas: 20
prefijo: b
```

#### B. Lectura dinámica en el bucle sin almacenar variables

Este tipo de lecturas es práctica cuando se quiere por ejemplo construir tablas en base a los datos del array.

```
foreach ($arrEdificios as $k=>$v)
{
    if (is_array ($v))
    {
        foreach ($v as $kk=>$vv)
        {
            echo "Llave: ".$kk. " Valor: ".$vv."\n";
        }  
            echo "\n";


    }else{
        echo "Llave: ".$k. " Valor: ".$v."\n";
    }
}
```

#### Salida:

```
Llave: nombre_edificio Valor: edificio1
Llave: numero_aulas Valor: 10
Llave: prefijo_aulas Valor: a

Llave: nombre_edificio Valor: edificio2
Llave: numero_aulas Valor: 20
Llave: prefijo_aulas Valor: b
```

---

### Demostración

**<kbd>[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/HBF18732)</kbd>**

Puedes probar y/o modificar todo el código anterior en línea.